# SQL Help. How to line up values on the same row, shift one column up?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, case

I am having a problem getting the columns to line up, the start_time is one row above the end_time.

This is my code:

```
SELECT  B.NAME
        ,MAX(case when DESCRIPTION = 'Green' then Final_Value end) as Start_Time
        ,MAX(case when DESCRIPTION = 'Red' then Final_Value end) as End_Time
          FROM mydata a
          JOIN ref_val B 
            ON A.ref_res = B.ref_res    
         WHERE B.COMPANY = 'abc'
         GROUP BY  B.NAME
```

This is what I want to get

```
The result looks like this:
    Name        Start_time              End_time           
1   John        5/6/15 6:30
2   John2       5/7/15 4:30           5/6/15 8:30          
3   Ben         5/8/15 2:30           5/7/15 7:25
4   Ben2        5/9/15 3:10           5/8/15 4:10

I want it to look like this:

    Name        Start_time              End_time            
1   John        5/6/15 6:30           5/6/15 8:30
2   John2       5/7/15 4:30           5/7/15 7:25         
3   Ben         5/8/15 2:30           5/8/15 4:10   
4   Ben2        5/9/15 3:10           5/9/15 5:20
```

Comment: What is your schema?

Comment: you may want to show the sample data before your query

Answer (score 1):

Use a window function with `LEAD`.  In this case, the most straight forward thing to do would be to nest your current query as written, then in the outer query, apply you partition.  See:

http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/

Answer (score 0):

A schema will help, but I suspect that the driving table should not be `mydata A`, but rather `ref_val b`, so that the group by and MAX makes more sense. I could be completely wrong based on actual schema:

```
SELECT  B.NAME
    ,MAX(case when DESCRIPTION = 'Green' then Final_Value end) as Start_Time
    ,MAX(case when DESCRIPTION = 'Red' then Final_Value end) as End_Time
      FROM ref_val B
      JOIN mydata A 
        ON A.ref_res = B.ref_res    
     WHERE B.COMPANY = 'abc'
     GROUP BY  B.NAME
```